# Rails Generate Paperclip Pin Image Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

I am receiving an error when running `rails generate paperclip pin image'. Below is the code, and I've also attached an image.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFkgX.png

```
Last login: Wed Nov 12 23:09:38 on ttys003
Jovans-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting jovanhernandez$ rails generate paperclip pin image
/Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/actions/create_migration.rb:13:in `migration_file_name': protected method `migration_file_name' called for #<PaperclipGenerator:0x007fb290c350b0> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/actions/create_migration.rb:34:in `existing_migration'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:112:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/create_file.rb:60:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:34:in `create_migration'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb:63:in `migration_template'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/paperclip-3.5.4/lib/generators/paperclip/paperclip_generator.rb:16:in `generate_migration'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:135:in `generate_or_destroy'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/jovanhernandez/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
Jovans-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting jovanhernandez$
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'` to your gemfile.

Credit goes to: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1495

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had a version of paperclip specified in my gemfile that was too old to work with my other versions. Maybe just update the gemfile's version number with something like

gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3'

Be sure you 
$ bundle install
after updating the version, and before you say 
$ rails generate paperclip pin image